# How to validate user input email format in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

I would like to get users to enter their email address before running the script and i am doing it like below:

```
:input
set /p email="Please enter your email address: "
(echo %email% | findstr "@ [] "%email:~7,1%"==""" >nul 2>&1) && (ECHO valid email >nul) || (echo This is not a valid email address.Please try again.) && GOTO Input
```

With the above code i am able to check on any blank space, presence of @ and atleast 7 chars in the email (i.e even if user types dummy a@b.com) but i am not sure how to check the case where user could just type (@b.com) where nothing is before @. Also i would like to disable or silent "TAB" for the users in the input field so that they can't use TAB.

I am open to doing this whole email format check in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution :

```dos
@echo off
echo Type your e-mail address :
Set /p "Email="
Call :CheckValidMail %Email%
cls
IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" ( 
    Color 0A
    echo %Email% is valid 
) else (
    Color 0C
    echo %Email% is not valid
)
pause & Exit
::*********************************************************************************
:CheckValidMail <Email>
(
echo If IsValidEmail("%~1"^) = True Then
echo    Wscript.Quit(0^)
echo Else
echo    Wscript.Quit(1^)
echo End If
echo Function IsValidEmail(strEAddress^)
echo    Dim objRegExpr
echo    Set objRegExpr = New RegExp
echo    objRegExpr.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[\w-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$"
echo    objRegExpr.Global = True
echo    objRegExpr.IgnoreCase = False
echo    IsValidEmail = objRegExpr.Test(strEAddress^)
echo    Set objRegExpr = Nothing
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Will test it out. Just wondering since this has got VB in it, are there any potential dependency for running such a script especially because i would want to work on any machine ?

Comment: Thanks this works well !! Could you please help me with my query "Just wondering since this has got VB in it, are there any potential dependency for running such a script especially because i would want to work on any machine ?"

Comment: You can play with it on any machine without any dependency :)